# How to restart kafka server properly?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Every time I stop the kafka server and start it again it doesn't start properly and I have to restart my whole machine and start the kafka server.
Does anybody know how I can restart kafka server without having to restart my machine?
Actually I would like to terminate the consumer from last session.

Thank you,

Zeinab

Answer (score 20):

If your Kafka broker is running as a service (found under `/lib/systemd/system/`) from a recent Confluent Platform release, you can stop it using:

```
systemctl stop confluent-kafka.service
```

or if you'd like to restart the service,

```
systemctl restart confluent-kafka.service
```

---

Otherwise, you can stop your broker using

```
./bin/kafka-server-stop.sh
```

and re-start it:

```
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

---

If you want to stop a specific consumer, simply find the corresponding process id:

```
ps -ef | grep consumer_name
```

and kill that process:

```
kill -9 process_id
```

Comment: After enter the commad:- bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties kafka server is not start

Comment: Not showing any error  after enter doesnt showing any process

Answer (score 6):

Or simply:

```
sudo systemctl restart kafka
```